# Creating Bundle in osgi framework like felix

Tags: maven, maven-2, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I would like to create a simple bundle as maven project. Please let me know how can i do it. Actually i can create a bundle with using the existing pom but now i don't want to do that.I want to make it from scratch like mvn archetype:generate.

Any suggestion are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PaxConstruct was developed for this. Check this nice [tutorial](http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/pax_construct_from_zero_to)